# Are there limits to waters energy absorbtion capacity

Tags: water

I have a system where I heat water in a flask.
The water vapor generated is condensed and returns to the original container (not a pressurized system, but condensation system is efficient enough that there is no loss of vapor).

My goal is to have maximum amount of vapor. (The real goal is the condensate droplets that filter through plant material to extract water soluble components - Kumagawa extraction)

**Question:**

Is there a limit or plateau to the amount of energy the water can absorb/turn into vapor?

or

I have a 10l flask and a 1500W heating mantle. If I run the heating mantle at full power is there a possibility that the energy generated couldn't be absorbed by the water in the flask and used in turning it into vapor and thus would heat the electrical control circuits and outer casing of the heating mantle instead.

Comment: The system you describe is not *absorbing* energy: it is moving energy from one place to another. As long as the vapour can be condensed as fast as it is created the system will keep functioning.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about absorption. The vapour condensating isn't the limiting factor for the moment. My concern is if there is a point where energy transfer gets less efficient towards water and easier towards the heating mantle.

Answer (score 1):

The heat transfer is limited by the flask material heat transfer rate, which is proportional to the thermal gradient within the flask. The external flask temperature will follow.

On the water side, liquid can jump out of flask in form of the thick foam, powered by the vapour. This is the major limiting factor.

On external side, at high enough power, the eventual plastic holders/features may start to melt/decompose. At higher power, the flask may start shining red. Or start to melt if metallic.

Comment: No, It is not.The former is material constant, the latter is not. If we consider for simplicity a rectangular block model, then heat_transfer_rate = thermal_conductivity * area / thickness * temperature_difference

Comment: For glass, another limitation is endurance against thermal shocks

Comment: 1) My flask, diam 280mm & thickness 8mm) is made of borosilicate. I have tried to calculate the heat transfer rate and it seems to be around 2000W if I consider the heating mantle to be 200 °C and the extract boiling inside. So this should not be the choke point.
2) Does it mean that if the extract is forming foam then less energy is transfered to the extract and more to the heating mantle? 
3) I naively thought that the more I put energy into this system the more water vapour I get...

Comment: Sorry I deleted the first comment, a bit new to the format.

Comment: I mean with too much heat, water can boil out, especially if foaming, like if overheat boiling soup.

Comment: This hasn’t happened yet, but it is better to add nucleation centers if done with new glassware and pure water, to avoid humongous bubbles forming. 
I’m still trying to figure out if the water itself has a limit at which rate it can “accept“ energy

Comment: I did not have in mind overheating, rather continuous too high rate of vapour bubbles. No, water does not have such a limit,but a particular scenario often has.